# ¿Cómo cierro sesión en Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, login

No encuentro en ningún lado dónde cerrar sesión.

Answer (score 4):

1) ir a https://stackexchange.com

2) Arriba a la derecha, click donde dice **StackExchange**, luego en **log out**.

[image]